# PHP/HTML5/css3 : Generating Word Art for given text

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I would like to generate Word Art/Word Style that are generated in website like http://cooltext.com/. My Expectation is, When I input text and style, I would like to get styled word as image.

All your suggestion and inputs are welcome.

****In order to attain my expected output****

**Should I use relevant fonts? or I should use Any PHP/HTML5/CSS3 techniques?**

As I am beginner in all the above mentioned Language, Your Inputs are valuable for me.

Thanks

Comment: Use fonts whatever you want. Google for web fonts and use them.

Comment: Where is the code you tried? We are not here to write your code

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: I would like to your guideline/direction. Hence, its broad.  However, I tried to achieve my output by using fabric JS(library for HTML5). However, I am able to attain my output as limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use webfonts and style them with CSS.

Create your own webfonts using [Font Squirrel webfont generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) or webfonts provided by Google. Please make sure you have a license for using the webfont. A webfont is usually a few files, used for various browsers, so I would place them in a folder for convenience.

### In CSS there are 2 phases in webfont usage:

1. Define the font-face.
2. Use font-family for specific CSS elements/classes/id's

**For example:**
Let's say you have a webfont called Alef. You generate it and in the folder you get 8 files - 4 regular, 4 bold. For each group you have files with extensions .eot, .woff, .ttf and .svg

### Defining the font-family in a CSS file

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Alef';
src: url('Alef-Bold.eot');
src: url('Alef-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Alef-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Alef-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Alef-Bold.svg#alefbold') format('svg');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Alef';
src: url('Alef-Regular.eot');
src: url('Alef-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('Alef-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('Alef-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('Alef-Regular.svg#alefregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Notice the font-family name and font-weight definitions in the above CSS. The same font-family can have normal and bold font-weight and normal and italic font-style.

### Set a font-family for a CSS element/class/id

```
p, .alef, #someid {
  font-family: Alef;
}
```

### Use CSS to add effects to your text

Here are some [text effects for example, by css3gen.com](http://css3gen.com/css3-text-effects/)
For example, 3D text on .3dtext class:

```
.3dtext {
  color:#000000;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #bcbcbc, 4px 4px 0 #9c9c9c;
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer. I can attain my result with your's inputs. Thanks again.

Comment: You are very welcome

Comment: -1; this doesn't generate an image from the text as the original question requested, nor is sufficient to create the majority of the word art examples from [the OP's link](http://cooltext.com/), which include textured text, striped text, complex shadows (not mere gradients) around letters, lighting effects, text embossed on an irregularly shaped background object, and more. CSS alone simply does not have the features required to create the majority of the effects the OP has asked for.

Comment: For more complex graphic options I would use SVG templates. Rendering SVG to image can be done using JavaScript and Canvas. Check out the following discussion:
https://gist.github.com/gustavohenke/9073132